# Find 3x3 real matrix A such that $A^2 \neq I$ and $A^4 = I$, where I is identity matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Find $3 \times 3$ real matrix A such that $A^2 \neq I$ and $A^4 = I$, where $I$ is identity matrix.

I first thought that there is no such matrix and tried to show that using determinants, but all I get is that A has to have $detA=1$ or $-1$. Next I actually found such Matrix A= $\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$, but I did it through random manipulations and do not have any idea how to coherently write the answer. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** try to find a $2 \times 2$ matrix $B$ like this.  Then, consider the block matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{B & 0\\0&1}
$$
Think of rotation matrices.

---

Your answer is perfect!  What you've found is the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1 & 0\\0&B}
$$
where 
$$
B = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}
$$
is the rotation in $\Bbb R^2$ by $90^\circ$.  Since rotating by $90^\circ$ $4$ times brings you back to where you started, we have $B^4 = I_2$.  On the other hand, when we apply the rotation twice, we end up with a $180^\circ$ rotation, which is to say that $B^2 = -I_2$.
So, when we take the $4$th power, we find
$$
A^4 = \pmatrix{1^4&0\\0&B^4} = 
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&I_2} = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1} = I_3
$$
On the other hand,
$$
A^2 = \pmatrix{1^2&0\\0&B^2} = 
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-I_2} = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&-1} \neq I_3
$$
So, we have $A^4 = I_3$ and $A^2 \neq I_3$, which is exactly what we wanted.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: How were you able to yield this at the beginning: $$
\pmatrix{1 & 0\\0&B}
$$
where 
$$
B = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}$$?

Comment: @Grace I don't understand your question

Comment: Meaning, what led you to decide to find this: $$
\pmatrix{1 & 0\\0&B}
$$
where 
$$
B = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}
$$, when starting the problem? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Grace Are you asking how I knew that this particular matrix would be a solution?  I did not decide to use that particular matrix, that was the result that the asker got *"through random manipulations"*.

Comment: @Grace Or perhaps you're referring to my hint in the beginning.  In any case, I was able to solve things the way I did using [block-diagonal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices).

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: the matrix for a rotation by ...